Four color theorem vs six color theorem in graph theory
I am not sure I understand the purpose of 4 color theorem if 6 color theorem says that G is planar if its chromatic number is less than or equal to 6 because 4 is inside this bound.Or have I totally misunderstood it and they are actually saying different things?

The six color theorem says that, if a graph is planar, then its chromatic number is less than or equal to six. It does not say anything about the other way around. (For example, the chromatic number of the graph $K_{3,3}$ is only two, but it is not planar.) So, the four color theorem is stronger.

The 6 color theorem says that if a graph is planar, then it can be coloured by at most 6 colours. The 4 color theorem says that you can reduce 6 to 4, that is, 4 colours are sufficient.

Did you mean four where you typed folor in the title?

@HackR Aha ok but isn't it a useless bound tho? When we talk about chromatic number aren't we like more interested in the least number of ways we can color a graph?

Not the least number of ways, but with the least amount of colours. And 4 is obviously less than 6.

The four-color theorem was quite difficult to prove and this happened only in my lifetime. There would have been many years before that when a less strict bound would still have been better than none.

@HackR but if we claim that a graph is planar if the graph can be colored with 6 colors then by default isn't it also planar if it can be colored in 5 or 4 ways?

We don't claim a graph is planar if it can be colored with 6 colors (the complete graph on 6 vertices is not planar). We claim that if it is planar, then it can be colored with 6 colors.

@MartianInvader Okay in that case then isn't it useless considering 4 color theorem says if a graph is planar it can be colored with 4 colors?

Correct, unless you happen to be living before 1976, the year the 4-color theorem was proved. Or if you want to prove the given theorem directly, in which case proving the 6-color theorem is far easier.

A priori, we could have graphs that are planar and graphs that are not planar, with any chromatic number. Here is a table, populated with some examples:
\begin{array}{c|cc}
  & G\text{ is planar} & G\text{ is not planar} \\
\hline
\chi(G) =2 & \text{e.g. any tree} & \text{e.g. }K_{n,n} \text{ for }n \ge 3 \\
\chi(G) =3 & \text{e.g. odd cycles} & \text{e.g. the Petersen graph} \\
\chi(G) =4 & \text{e.g. }K_4 & \text{e.g. the Grötzsch graph} \\
\chi(G) =5 & ?? & \text{e.g. } K_5 \\
\chi(G) =6 & ?? & \text{e.g. } K_6 \\
\chi(G) =7 & ?? & \text{e.g. } K_7 \\
\chi(G) =8 & ?? & \text{e.g. } K_8
\end{array}
(Some links: Petersen graph, Grötzsch graph. The simplest example of a graph with chromatic number $n$ is $K_n$, but I don't mean to imply that all graphs with chromatic number $n$ must have a clique with $n$ vertices; this is misleading.)
The six-color theorem says that there are no examples where $G$ is planar but $\chi(G) > 6$. It excludes the cases marked with a red X:
\begin{array}{c|cc}
  & G\text{ is planar} & G\text{ is not planar} \\
\hline
\chi(G) =2 & \text{e.g. any tree} & \text{e.g. }K_{n,n} \text{ for }n \ge 3 \\
\chi(G) =3 & \text{e.g. odd cycles} & \text{e.g. the Petersen graph} \\
\chi(G) =4 & \text{e.g. }K_4 & \text{e.g. the Grötzsch graph} \\
\chi(G) =5 & ?? & \text{e.g. } K_5 \\
\chi(G) =6 & ?? & \text{e.g. } K_6 \\
\chi(G) =7 & \color{red}{\times} & \text{e.g. } K_7 \\
\chi(G) =8 & \color{red}{\times} & \text{e.g. } K_8
\end{array}
The four-color theorem is stronger: it says that there are no examples where $G$ is planar but $\chi(G) > 4$. It excludes all the cases which had question marks in them:
\begin{array}{c|cc}
  & G\text{ is planar} & G\text{ is not planar} \\
\hline
\chi(G) =2 & \text{e.g. any tree} & \text{e.g. }K_{n,n} \text{ for }n \ge 3 \\
\chi(G) =3 & \text{e.g. odd cycles} & \text{e.g. the Petersen graph} \\
\chi(G) =4 & \text{e.g. }K_4 & \text{e.g. the Grötzsch graph} \\
\chi(G) =5 & \color{red}{\times}  & \text{e.g. } K_5 \\
\chi(G) =6 & \color{red}{\times}  & \text{e.g. } K_6 \\
\chi(G) =7 & \color{red}{\times} & \text{e.g. } K_7 \\
\chi(G) =8 & \color{red}{\times} & \text{e.g. } K_8
\end{array}
The four-color theorem makes the six-color theorem redundant - it proves everything that the six-color theorem proves, and more. However, the six-color theorem is much simpler to prove, so it is still often used as an example in classes on graph theory. (The ideas behind the proof of the six-color theorem are also important; for example, they can be used to prove that the union of any two planar graphs is $12$-colorable.)
